# Using ES lint with browserify, missing fs Module error

Tags: javascript, browserify, eslint

Im trying to browserify the ESlint (latest version) and the problem that ES lint contain `fs module` and when I try to use it I got error, any idea how to overcome this ? 
I read the following but not sure that I understand if how to solve it,any idea how ?

Comment: As use of eslint in the browser is [not officially supported](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/7238), I think this question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gulp task to create the eslint bundle then you can use npm package '**vinyl-source-stream**' along with browserify.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var derequire = require('gulp-derequire');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var browserify = require('browserify');

gulp.task('js',function(){
    browserify('./app/app.js')
        .bundle()
        .on('error',function(e){
            gutil.log(e);
        })
        .pipe(source('bundle_lint.js'))
        .pipe(derequire())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/dist'));
});

gulp.task('default',['js']);

//app.js file code 
var eslint = require('eslint');
```